# easyui datagrid insertrow get input value

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I mean I want to insert a new row in datagrid to use insertrow method.

but the rows parameter is fixed ,i want to get the new values when i click save button

code belows.

```
$("#insertRow").click(function(){

var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
if (row){
    var index = $('#dg').datagrid('getRowIndex', row);
} else {
    index = 0;
}
$('#dg').datagrid('insertRow', {
    index: index,
    row:{long:row.long} //I mean this place must be the value i typed ,like row.long
});

$('#dg').datagrid('selectRow',index);
$('#dg').datagrid('beginEdit',index);   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this if you want to set the blank value

```
$('#dg').datagrid('insertRow', {
index: index,
row:{long:''}
});
```

and `row:{long:'long1'}` to set the value to the field
** if this is not helping, please provide your datagrid code and please more explicit of your code `row:{long:row.long}`